# Current UIView Questions iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I posted earlier but am running into similar problems again. Basically the way that my app is setup there is a top bar that is basically just a static image that has UIButtons placed on top of it. That is the Main View Controller and is persistent no matter what view is shown beneath it. I can't use a navigation controller because it is not possible to change the height and I need the bar to be significantly larger than a navbar. However my bar is functioning in much the same way. There is a "Home" Button, a "Back" Button and several destination buttons.

I understand how to switch views from say the home screen. My confusion comes with the back button. In order to press back the app is going to need to know what view is currently being displayed so that it can be removed from view and a new subview can be added. Ideally I would use the UINavigationController so that I can push and pop views which is really what I want to do here, however that is not possible because of the visual problem.

Does anybody know of a method that returns the current displayed view so I could do something like the following

```
[currentview.view removeFromSuperView];
[self.view insertSubview:experienceViewController.view atIndex:0]
```

Comment: How many controllers do you have? I mean do you have controllers for every view you are displaying or only one controller handling all the views which are to be displayed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use UINavigationController with the nav bar hidden. Put the nav controller inside a view that does have your jumbo toolbar and you'll have access to the push/pop behavior you're looking for.